# Does a AWS RDS instance update itself if it is setup in a private VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

If I launch a RDS instance in one of my private VPCs, will that be able to update itself provided that I have enabled **Auto Minor Version Upgrade**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon RDS is a fully-managed service. All maintenance is performed by AWS "in the background" and **does not involve traffic going through your VPC**. (This also applies to snapshots and instance modifications, such as changing the DB instance type.)

Minor version upgrades may involve an outage period.

If you are running in **Multi-AZ mode**, then the Secondary server is upgraded, the Secondary server becomes the new Master server and then the old Master is updated and becomes the new Secondary server. This means that applications will be disconnect and need to reconnect to the database, but there is no outage period.